# Array data type editing in form with changing order of items

Tags: qgis, postgresql

Is it possible to changing order of items array data type in editing form?

[image: Standart editing form for array do not allow changing order of items]

Alternatively, what other way to work with ordering, when I could not think of any other way than using an array?

QGIS version: 3.16

PostgreSQL table SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE public.example
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('example_id_seq'::regclass),
    ordering integer[],
    CONSTRAINT example_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```